# sending email in laravel difficulties

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to send an mail in laravel. Not sure if im doing it correctly but I based everything on tutorials, and trying to keep it as simple as possible.
What am i doing wrong? It currently gives me an error that: *"Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, string "*
If i leave an empty $data it says its undefined. Im not sure how to do all these things. Any help please?

```
 $data = "helloooo";

 Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) { 
 $message->to('thatsmymail123@gmail.com', 'me')->subject('Welcome!'); });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clue is in your error. "Argument 2 passed to `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send()` must be of the type array, string given"

The array you need to pass to the `Mail::send()` function is exactly the same as the usual way a view is rendered.

For example you might do this to render a view.

```
$data['foo'] = 'bar';

return View::make('my.view', $data);
```

In your view you then have a variable of `$foo` available. The same applies to sending an email. Laravel still needs to render your view for the email. To solve your problem above...

```
$data = ['foo' => 'bar'];

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('email@example.com', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

If you don't have/need any data to be passed to your view, just use an empty array.

```
$data = []; // Empty array

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('email@example.com', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's weird that you can't skip the array.

Comment: @Arcrammer PHP doesn't have method overloading like Java and other languages do. If you want to supply the third parameter the second must be present.

Answer (score 0):

$data = "helloooo";
Instead using $data make it array. Like this
$data['message'] = "helloooo";

As the argument passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, so we passed it in array format.

and in email view: emails.welcome
use $message to show your variable value.